# Cannot Set To Front an UIImage

Tags: ios

I have a `ViewController` with two `UIImage's`. The first one is just a small `UIImage` (artwork) and the second occupies the all `ViewController` (background). I want my artwork `UIImage` to be on top of the background image. But all of the options from the `Editor -> Arrange` are disabled.

I also tried to adjust the `UIImage's` from the `View Controller Scene`. The artwork `UIImage` is below the background `UIImage` which should be correct, but when I run the app I can see only the background `UIImage`.

I am using the same image for both of the `UIImage's`. And I use `Xcode 6`.

Here is a print screen:

[image]

Comment: I think, your problem is another. According to the order of your UIImageView in storyboards, your artwork is in front to your background. I order to debugging is good think use background color to both UIImageView (like red and blue), and make sure your artwork has dimensions, is in the screen, is no hidden...But don´t miss your time with the position, now is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Autolayout enabled in your project? If yes please check the position of the small image view when run.

For that just log the location as

```
NSLog(@"loc : %f %f",artworkImgView.frame.origin.x,artworkImgView.frame.origin.y);
```

Check whether the location is same as that given in storyboard.
To solve the issue, you can set the proper constraints.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: look like I am getting 0.00 and 0.00 for the location. I also changed the artwork color to red, and the background is blur, so I should see the artwork image, but I dont. What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In code you can write in viewdidload:

```
[self.view bringsubViewToFront:image];
```